# how to get id of any element on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to have an alert pop up when *any* element on the page is clicked that tells you the tag name (or id or whatever other information) about that element?
I basically want to set up the following for every element:

```
$('#wrapper').click(function() {
            alert($(this).prop('tagName'));
        })
```

Except I don't want to write that code for every single element on the page as that would take forever and would be extremely impractical in every way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind your listener on a global object with a selector.

```
$(document).on('click', '*', function() {
  alert($(this).prop('tagName'));
});
```

should work.

Comment: Why are you including the second parameter? There should be no reason to specify `"*"`. Any click should bubble up to the `document`

Comment: @lan If you don't specify it, you're only listening to the click on the element itself (you could then access the tagName by using the event variable though). Here I'm listening to the clicks of all the descendants directly.

Comment: That's not at all true. Any clicks that happen **inside** of it will bubble up to it. The fact that you use `document` means it's handling the parent-most element, and therefore **every** element on the page. When you click a `<div>` for example, it bubbles up and every ancestor will catch the event. You're just adding extra work for jQuery

Answer (score 0):

```
document.body.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
       e = e || window.event;
       alert(e.toElement.getAttribute("id"));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this

```
$(document).on('click', '*', function() {
    // Set clicked element's id to variable
    var elementName = $(this).attr('id');
    // Alert displaying id of clicked element
    alert(elementName);
})
```

Comment: When I downvoted your answer was `$('*').click(...);`.  I'll remove it now that it's more sane :)

Comment: Actually, it won't let me remove it for some reason. Says it's "locked in".

Comment: Apologies. It was worded as a complete answer at the time (and I don't really see how `$('*').click(...);` is a partially typed version of `$(document).on('click', '*', ...);`), but that's besides the point I guess...

Comment: Looks like if you make another edit I can remove my vote, though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an pure javascript method:

```
document.onclick = function(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        var o = e.srcElement||e.target;
        alert(o.id);
    }
```